# Blade not using the css style of the navbar on a specific page

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a main.blade file with the partial for the navigation bar which includes the css styles which work fine on all of the pages besides one page. The only difference between this page and other pages is that it is a resource (using CRUD controller). Why I can not see the css of the navigation bar?

Here is my code:

main.blade

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

@include('partials._head')
<body>

    @include('partials._nav')


        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>

    @include('partials._javascript')

    @yield('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

the not working page:

```
@extends('main')

@section('content')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

        <h1> Create New Post </h1>
        <hr>

        {!! Form::open(['route' => 'posts.store', 'data-parsley-validate' => '', 'files' => true]) !!}

        {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control','required' => '')) !!}

        {!! Form::label('slug', 'Slug:')!!}
        {!! Form::text('slug', null, array('class' => 'form-control',
                                          'required' => '', 'minlength' => '5', 'maxlength' => '255')) !!}
        {!! Form::label('category_id', 'Category:') !!}
        <select class="form-control" name="category_id">
            @foreach($categories as $category)
                <option value='{{ $category->id }}'> {{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>


        {!! Form::label('body', 'Post Body:') !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('body', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}

        {!! Form::submit('Create Post', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block', 'style' => 'margin-top: 20px')) !!}

        {!! Form::close() !!}

    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

_navbar.blade.php (included in main)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/color/rose.css">

<nav  class=" nim-menu navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container1">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Serv<span class="themecolor">i</span>ce</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            @if (Auth::check())
            <li><a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ route('categories') }}">Categories</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ route('posts.create') }}">Create a Post</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ route('contact') }}">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">My Posts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
            @else
            <li><a href="dashboard" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="categories">Categories</a></li>
            <li><a href="createPost">Create a Post</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="login">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="register">Register</a></li>
            @endif
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Remove relevant code until it appears again and then debug from there. The most likely issue is some type of malformed HTML element or something.

Comment: I use the same structure for all the pages but this page appears to be the only one that does not apply the css (shows the navigation bar from main blade but does not apply the css from the _navigation partial)

Comment: use always base url to link your css and js file. Post how you are linking your styles

Comment: I will update now the post

Comment: If you inspect your HTML code, this is generated? or there is applied some CSS rule don't allow see it?

Comment: css and js place in public folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All css and js move to public folder and replace below twe line with _nav file lines

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::to('css/style1.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::to('css/color/rose.css') }}">
```

i hope it's work. if not comment below